# For homomorphism $\Phi$, $\Phi(x^n) = (\Phi(x))^n$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to trying to prove this following result:

> Let $\Phi: G \to G'$ be a group homomorphism. Prove that for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x \in G$, $\Phi(x^n) = (\Phi(x))^n$.

I'm not sure if there is a better, more efficient way to prove this, but the natural strategy to me seems to be induction for the non-negative side and closure under inverses for the negative side.

> **Solution.** For integers $n \geq 0$, we proceed by induction.
>
> Base Case ($n = 0$): If $n = 0$, $x^n = e_G$, and $\Phi(e_G) = e_{G'}$. Similarly, $(\Phi(x))^0 = e_{G'}$.
>
> Induction Hypothesis: Assume for $n = k$: 
>   $$\Phi(x^k) = (\Phi(x))^k.$$
>
> Induction Step: Prove for $n = k + 1$: 
>   \begin{align*}
> \Phi(x^{k+1}) & = \Phi((x^k) x)  \\
> & = \Phi(x^k) \Phi(x) \\
> & = (\Phi(x))^k \Phi(x)  \\
> & = (\Phi(x))^{k+1}  
> \end{align*}
>   So for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\Phi(x^n) = ((\Phi(x))^n$. By taking inverses (since they are unique), this implies that $\Phi(x^n)^{-1} = ((\Phi(x))^{-n}$, which gives $\Phi(x^{-n}) = ((\Phi(x))^{-n}$.

Comment: It seems fine to me. Well done :)

Comment: The proof is both correct and easy to follow. Induction is the natural way to prove this so your intuition seems sharp as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to get the question off the unanswered list: yes, your proof is correct. It is well-written and easy to follow. Good job!